# Calculate the values of the "trigonometric" functions for the angles $a+b$ and $a-b$

Tags: trigonometry

Calculate the values of the "trigonometric" functions for the angles $a+b$ and $a-b$ if
$\sin a =\frac{3}{5} \, y\, \sin b= \frac{2\sqrt{13}}{13}$

I did for $\sin(a+b) = \sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)= \frac{3}{5}\cos(b)+\frac{2\sqrt{13}}{13}\cos(a)$

but I don't know if am I the correct way and how to know how much is $\cos(b) $ and $\cos(a)$ how can I calculate it? just with calculator?

Comment: Use the formula $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1.$  Presumably, you are allowed to assume that $\cos a$ and $\cos b$ are both positive.  Without an assumption like this, the problem can't be solved.  Also, $\cos (a+b) = (\cos a \cos b) - (\sin a \sin b).$

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 concepts (which I am assuming you already know):

1.) Definition of $\tan x$ and $\cot x$ in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$

2.) Reciprocal-relations like $\sin{x}=\frac{1}{\operatorname{cosec}x}$

3.) Trigonometric identities which are based on Pythagoras theorem like $\sin^2 {x}+\cos^2{x}=1$ (note this identity was proved using Pythagoras theorem)

Now, we have 3 such reciprocal relations and 3 such identities based on the Pythagoras theorem (there are more trigonometric identities based on the Pythagoras theorem, but we can generally derive all of them from these 3 fundamental identities).

The best part of those above concepts is that they let us find any trigonometric ratio easily if we already know one. As:

If $\sin{x}=\frac{1}{2}$ then,
$\operatorname{cosec} x=\frac{1}{\sin x}=2$

and, $\sin^2 {x}+\cos^2{x}=1$
$\Rightarrow\cos^2{x}=1-\frac{1}{4}$
$\Rightarrow \cos^2 x= \frac{3}{4} \Rightarrow \cos x=\pm \frac {\sqrt3}{2}$

Now, if we have this angle $x$ only defined for a right-angled triangle, then we can say that $\cos x \neq -\frac {\sqrt 3}{2}$, since trigonometric ratios of angle $x$ where $0°\lt x \lt 90°$, are always positive. So, that gives us $\cos x= \frac {\sqrt3}{2}$

However, if $x$ is defined for any angle then both values of $\cos x$ is right. So, $\cos x= \pm \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$

Now we can find $\sec x$ by reciprocal relation and $\tan x$ and $\cot x$ by their definition.

If we have taken $x$ as any angle, you can observe $x$ belongs from 1st or 2nd quadrant, since $\sin x$ which is $\frac {1}{2}$, is positive. So, we will get $\operatorname {cosec} x$ positive and $\cos x$, $\sec x$, $\tan x$ and $\cot x$ either positive or negative.

I also want to suggest that once you have found one trigonometric ratio of $a+b$, use that ratio to find other ratios of $a+b$ rather than writing compound angle formulae for each trigonometric ratio of $a+b$. (Similar with $a-b$)

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$$
$\sin(a)=\dfrac 3 5$ implies a right triangle with hypotenuse $5$ and side opposite $a$ of $3$

$\therefore$ side adjacent to $a$ is $4$ $\implies \cos(a)=\dfrac 4 5$
Now, $\dfrac {2\sqrt{13}} {13}=\dfrac 2 {\sqrt{13}}$, implying a hypotenuse of $\sqrt{13}$, opposite of $2$, and by Pythagoras, adjacent of $3$.
$\therefore \cos(b)=\dfrac 3 {\sqrt{13}}$
Substitution into angle formula and simplifying gives $\sin(a+b)=\dfrac {17\sqrt{13}} {65} $
I'll leave $\sin(a-b)$ to you.